# Getting error Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) on Android Adapter

Tags: java, android, segmentation-fault

I am getting the following error on an `Adapter` on `getView` on android:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x187 in tid 20034 (kup.android.app)
```

I have a list of chat messages that is populating the adapter. What I am doing is getting the message from the list of adapters, then find out who is the user that sent the message, and finally get their ID:

```
int id = mChatMessages.get(position).getFrom().getId();
```

If I put an breakpoint on this line and just click resume program as soon as the debugger stops there it works fine. The problem only happens if I do not have any breakpoints.

This is `getFrom` on `ChatMessage`:

```
private User from;
public User getFrom() {
    return from;
}
```

and this is `getID` on `User`:

```
private int id;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

And this is `getView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    ChatMessage message = mChatMessages.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        int id = message.getFrom().getId();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);
        holder.isMyMessage = (id == currentUser.getId());

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.message.setText(message.getContent());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code of `getView()` ?

Comment: Are you sure `message` and `getFrom()` is correctly initialized? Seems like you trying to access wrong memory or call method from null object.

Comment: I do not know why this is happening. It all seems correct to me. I noticed that it works correctly if I make `id` public on `User`, and use  `message.getFrom().id` on `getView()`.

Comment: Try `Integer` instead `int`. It's interesting what would happen.

Comment: I get the same error with `Integer`. The error happens when calling `getId()`, it never gets to `return id;` from `getId()`. I tried saving the value from `message.getFrom()` to a variable named `user`, and then from there calling `getId()`, but it was the same. I added a log to see the serialized contents of `user` just before calling `getId()` and I stopped getting the error. I was doing this to avoid using the breakpoint. I think it had the same effect, it seems that that small wait makes the difference.